# parsing data from ps -ef

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have my output below:

```
ps -ef | grep logstash
kafka     2832     1  1 Oct06 ?        08:18:36 /usr/bin/java -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx1g -Xss2048k -Djffi.boot.library.path=/apps/COMPASSLOG_DEV/logstash-2.2.2/vendor/jruby/lib/jni -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/apps/COMPASSLOG_DEV/logstash-2.2.2/heapdump.hprof -Xbootclasspath/a:/apps/COMPASSLOG_DEV/logstash-2.2.2/vendor/jruby/lib/jruby.jar -classpath : -Djruby.home=/apps/COMPASSLOG_DEV/logstash-2.2.2/vendor/jruby -Djruby.lib=/apps/COMPASSLOG_DEV/logstash-2.2.2/vendor/jruby/lib -Djruby.script=jruby -Djruby.shell=/bin/sh org.jruby.Main --1.9 /apps/COMPASSLOG_DEV/logstash-2.2.2/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb logstash/runner.rb agent -f /apps/COMPASSLOG_DEV/COMPASSLOG_DEV.config
```

I have used the script below to make it look clean:

```
ps -ef | grep logstash | grep -v grep | grep -v nohup|awk '{print $38}'|awk -F/ '{print $3}'|awk -F_ '{print "Logstash is running for: "$1$2}'
```

which gives me output:

```
Logstash is running for: COMPASSLOGDEV
```

How can I add the port number its running on as below?

```
Logstash is running for: COMPASSLOGDEV on port number 2832
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ add this
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more on asking questions that will attract quality answers.

Comment: thats not the port, thats the pid

Comment: you are right ! I meant to say the pid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ps -ef | grep logstash | awk -F" " '{print "Logstash is running for " substr($NF,7,10) substr($NF, 18,3)" on port number " $2 }'
```

Using space as delimiter:

`$2` is port 2832

`substr($NF,7, 10)` is COMPASSSLOG

`substr($NF, 18, 3` is DEV

The above get what you want, but **as @Farhad mentioned.  2832 IS PID OTHER THAN PORT NUMBER**

Comment: Works like a charm !

Comment: You can make it even neater by removing the `grep`. Try this-

`ps -ef | awk -F" " '/logstash/ {print "Logstash ...`